# WebBrowser Controle

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, browser, webbrowser-control

Does any one have any custom web-browser control for windows mobile?.
i tried using default WebBrowser control for windows mobile in c#, it gives me lot of problem like,
it does't have gestures,it doesn't open some of sites like "icicibank.com" and many more...,
i just done a quick googling on this i found this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/975281) given by Microsoft.

i have tried using an ATL controle IWebBrowser2, it works fine, but its in ATL,
i want similar controle in C#, how can i get..
please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NETCF 3.5 and are having issues with the embedded web browser control, Microsoft has posted a hotfix. You can request the fix here: http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=975281&kbln=en-us. This is specific to the Knowledge Base article: KB975281.